# Git: Amend previous commit to change misinterpreted rename

Tags: git, git-merge

While merging, GIT misinterpreted a file creation as rename since there was a similar file (with 80% similarity) deleted. I have noticed this only after merging everything.

Is there a way I can correct GIT and amend my previous commit. I know there is `--amend` option for `git commit`. What I am looking for is a way to modify the status of change.

Comment: Git doesn't actually track changes. It doesn't distinguish between a rename and a delete+add.  So long as your end state is correct, there's nothing to amend here.

Comment: To add to @OliverCharlesworth comment, the rename/copy detection is not a part of the stored data. It is instead determined when displaying changes/summaries. If you take a look at the `git diff` help there are flags to control it `-M` to manipulate rename threshold, `--no-renames` to turn it off completely. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Mltngt

Comment: Does that mean it is a client problem not Git's? The git clients and the BitBucket page disply it as rename.

Comment: @MaheshVS: yes. The command-line client has a flag, `--find-renames=<number>` and `--no-renames`, to tell it whether, when looking at a commit, to guess at whether the file was renamed from a previous commit, and if so, to control the similarity required. If the web and/or GUI clients lack the flag, that just means they lack the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments:

The misinterpretation is done when displaying the changes not in the storage and thus no need to amend the original commit. However, using command-line parameters such as --find-renames= and --no-renames we can control this display behavior. It is up to the git client to support such features.